# Can't Verify "PGP SIGNED MESSAGE" in Linux

Tags: linux, gnupg, pgp

**gpg ver. 2.1.18;  Debian Stretch**

Public key duly imported from https://cygwin.com/key/pubring.asc

I downloaded a pair of cygwin installation files from https://cygwin.com/install.html and they passed the verify test:

i.e. `gpg --verify setup-x86_64.exe.sig setup-x86_64.exe` yielded nothing untoward...

I was happy at that point and should have stopped there. However, I noticed on said
**Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages** page, in the **Signing key transition section**, a link to a message in the **Cygwin-announce mailing list** (https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-March/009447.html).

Well, try as I might, I could not verify said message in what I thought was the normal fashion - i.e. I saved said message to a text file (**cygwin.asc**), starting with the ***-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----*** line and ending with the ***-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----*** line, and ran

`gpg --verify cygwin.asc`

Which resulted in:

```
gpg: Signature made Fri 13 Mar 2020 09:44:49 AM MDT
gpg:                using DSA key 1169DF9F22734F743AA59232A9A262FF676041BA
gpg: Good signature from "Cygwin <cygwin@cygwin.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 1169 DF9F 2273 4F74 3AA5  9232 A9A2 62FF 6760 41BA
gpg: Signature made Fri 13 Mar 2020 09:44:49 AM MDT
gpg:                using RSA key 56405CF6FCC81574682A5D561A698DE9E2E56300
gpg: Good signature from "Cygwin <cygwin@cygwin.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 5640 5CF6 FCC8 1574 682A  5D56 1A69 8DE9 E2E5 6300
gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error
```

The only way I could eliminate said

```
gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error
```

squawk was to, in said **cygwin.asc** file, truncate the public key section of the message (thus creating the **cygwin-no-pubkey.asc** file).

Then:

```
$ gpg --verify cygwin-no-pubkey.asc 
gpg: Signature made Fri 13 Mar 2020 09:44:49 AM MDT
gpg:                using DSA key 1169DF9F22734F743AA59232A9A262FF676041BA
gpg: Good signature from "Cygwin <cygwin@cygwin.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 1169 DF9F 2273 4F74 3AA5  9232 A9A2 62FF 6760 41BA
gpg: Signature made Fri 13 Mar 2020 09:44:49 AM MDT
gpg:                using RSA key 56405CF6FCC81574682A5D561A698DE9E2E56300
gpg: Good signature from "Cygwin <cygwin@cygwin.com>" [unknown]
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 5640 5CF6 FCC8 1574 682A  5D56 1A69 8DE9 E2E5 6300
```

which looked copasetic to me!

What is going on here? Why did I have to remove the public key block from the subject message in order to achieve goodness? I looked for hours, including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48439906/can-not-verify-pgp-signed-text-with-gnupgp) with no joy!:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final line stating `gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error` results when `gpg --verify` encounters **non-signature** OpenPGP data (the public key block), but this does not negate the previous output showing the signatures were successfully verified.

This is expected behavior. Cygwin could have included in their [instructions](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/cygwin-announce/2020-March/009447.html) (which says to save both the clearsigned text and public key block in the same file) a statement alerting users to this.

Comment: That is a clear explanation! I take it then that I should be satisfied when I see, in the output from the `gpg --verify` command, something like (forgive the formatting): `gpg: Signature made...`  `gpg:                using DSA key ...` `gpg: Good signature from ...` , assuming that the fingerprint looks good?

Comment: @Digger Yes, in this case the error can be safely ignored as long as you see `gpg: Good signature` with the correct key fingerprints.